# Disabling the pop up

Tags: popup

Using python selenium
I am using this code provide below the site URL is mentioned in the code when we open URL a pop up window appears i want to disable that pop up window I tried this code to disable the pop up when site load it shows a pop up to add "address to check visibility" but code is not working.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
website = "https://www.ubereats.com/gb/store/ammas-kitchen/6AchIeiCS16x5hOVfAhbTQ"
driver.get(website)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
options.add_experimental_option(
    "prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1}
)
```